# How to load text file using pandas?

Tags: pandas, load

For example I have this text file named "abc.txt" as below:

```
#Name : abc
#Date : 1/1/2000
#Country : USA
9000  32  5143  16
2172  26  9162  22
1616  25  7181  40
4626  51  9299  77
```

I would only want to extract the numbers into dataframe excluding the Name, Date and Country rows

Comment: try using read csv: `pd.read_csv('file.txt',sep='\t',skiprows=range(3),header=None)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `abc.txt` is not a CSV file, you can still use the `pandas.read_csv()` function, since the file is CSV-like enough. Since you want to skip the first three rows, pass any iterable containing the corresponding row index (in this case, that would be any iterable containing `0`, `1`, and `2`). However, passing `range(3)` would probably be easiest. Since there are no headers, you'll also want to pass `header=None`.

```py
>>> pandas.read_csv(
    "abc.txt", delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=range(3), header=None
)
      0   1     2   3
0  9000  32  5143  16
1  2172  26  9162  22
2  1616  25  7181  40
3  4626  51  9299  77
```